# Absolute irreducibility of affine varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $V$ be an irreducible affine variety over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, , given in terms of equations over $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $q$ is some prime power. Are there any methods to decide whether $V$ remains irreducible over the algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$?

Comment: How did you check it was irreducible over $\mathbb F_q$?

Comment: For two variables case, I used Eisenstein s criterion

Comment: Why not apply Eisenstein's criterion over $\overline{\mathbb F_q}$?

Comment: Affine variety is defined by several equations. Eisenstein's criterion is very limited in application.

Comment: But how is the base field relevant for this? If it works over $\mathbb F_q$ then it works over $\overline{\mathbb F_q}$.

Comment: This may be a stupid question but can I ask about a variety over a finite field being irreducible? A finite set of points is only irreducible if it’s a single point. When you say your variety over a finite field is irreducible what exactly do you mean?

Comment: If what you mean is that the variety lives in affine space over the algebraic closure $\mathbb{A}^n(\overline{\mathbb{F}_q})$, but it’s just defined over a finite field, then like Will Sawin says, the field of definition shouldn’t matter.

Comment: $x^2 + y^2$ is not irreducible over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ because it has $\sqrt{-1}$,but it irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$ when $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$

Comment: **Question:** "Let V be an irreducible affine variety over a finite field Fq, , given in terms of equations over Fq, where q is some prime power. Are there any methods to decide whether V remains irreducible over the algebraic closure of Fq?"
$$\text{  }$$
**Answer:** If $V:=Spec(k[x_1,..,x_n]/\mathfrak{p})$ with $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal and $k:=\mathbb{F}_q, q:=p^r$ with $K$ the algebraic closure of $k$. It follows $V$ is geometrically irreducible iff $V\otimes_k K:=Spec(K[x_1,..,x_n]/\tilde{\mathfrak{p}})$ is irreducible.

Comment: Hence you must check that your ideal $\tilde{\mathfrak{p}} \subseteq K[x_1,..,x_n]$ is a prime ideal. I do not think there is a "general criterion" for checking this given a set of generators for $\mathfrak{p}$. 
$$\text{  }$$
**Example:** Note that if $f\in k[x_1^p,..,x_n^p] \subseteq A:=k[x_1,..,x_n]$ it follows $f=g^p$ in $K[x_1,..,x_n]$. Hence $X:=Spec(A/(f))$ is not geometrically irreducible: The ideal $\mathfrak{p}:=(f) \subseteq A$ may be prime but $\tilde{\mathfrak{p}}:=(f)$ is never prime in $A\otimes_k K$.

Comment: More generally if $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq k[x_i^p]$ is a prime ideal it follows $\tilde{\mathfrak{p}} \subseteq K[x_i]$ is "seldom" a prime ideal.

Comment: **My comment:** The above comment was deleted by David White and Kohl, still it may have interest to some readers of this forum.

Comment: @hm2020 Thank you for your comments.